# The use and alternatives for "investigate"

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

> I've been **investigating** the company but there is little information about it.

To investigate:

- to inquire into (a situation or problem) thoroughly; examine systematically, esp. in order to discover the truth (Collins Dictionary)

Investigating is often associated with officials searching into an event, a situation or a claim so as to learn some facts about it.

However, the sentence above is about someone looking for information about a company, trying to find out more about it (before an interview). *Investigate* doesn't seem to be the right word in this context. Which alternatives would be better?

Comment: *Investigating* sounds find to me. But if you want an alternative, *researching* might work better for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone can **investigate** anything; it doesn't have to be a formal investigation. It implies a more serious, focussed inquiry than **researching** something; investigation is for some focussed purpose, to make a decision or work out what happened, or determine what the situation really is, while research is just finding out about something.

In the case of preparing for an interview, it's reasonable to use either. There's a clear focus that makes *investigate* reasonable, though it would be more likely if they suspected something non-obvious was going to be relevant to the interview. *Research* works in any case.